# Rails nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, reddit

I am learning Rails and making a reddit clone to help me understand how routing works.

Each post has subreddit. I have the following in my routes file:

```
resources :subreddits  do
 resources :posts
end
```

This way I can create new posts with the following url:

```
/subreddits/:subreddit_id/posts/new(.:format)
```

Example:

```
http://localhost:3000/subreddits/1/posts/new
```

However I still need to specify in the new posts form what subreddit I want to post to belong to. Wheras what I want is a hidden field that sets the subreddit id to the correct one. The correct one being the one given in the URL.

This is what I currently have:

```
=simple_form_for @post, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
-if @post.errors.any?
    #errors
        %h2
        =pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")
        prevented this pin from saving
        %ul
            -@post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                %li= msg


.form-group
    =f.input :title, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}

.form-group
    =f.input :content, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}

=f.hidden_field :subreddit_id, :value => @post.subreddit_id

=f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>33, :subreddit_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:subreddit_id]
```

I think this is because I am trying to access the subreddit id of a post that hasn't been created yet. How do I solve this? Am I going about it in the wrong direction?

Comment: could you post the code that builds the url in the form builder? (ie more of your template file)

Comment: @Bobby Matson Ive added the rest of the code from the new posts view. If thats what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `new` action of the posts_controller, you'll set the `@subreddit` instance variable

```
def new
  @subreddit = Subreddit.find(params[:subreddit_id])
  @post = Post.new
end
```

In the form, you'll need to change the first line

```
= simple_form_for [@subreddit, @post], html: {multipart: true} do |f|
```

:subreddit_id will now be in the url

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check if it works

```
= f.input :title, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "some value" }
```